# React Native: Pass settings from custom component to TextInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a custom component called TextInputField.js:

```
import React from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    StyleSheet
} from "react-native";

const TextInputField = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.inputWrapper}>
      <Text style={styles.inputLabel}>{props.label}</Text>
      <TextInput {...props} style={styles.inputField} />
      <Text style={styles.inputCaption}>{props.caption}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default TextInputField;
```

Which I'm using like this:

```
<TextInputField 
  label='Test'
  caption='Sample'
  multiline={true}
  numberOfLines={4}
  onChangeText={(text) => {
    onChangeTextHandler(text);
  }}
/>
```

Label and caption work fine.

Everything works fine in this [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@warm__tape/custom-input).

My question is: how do I ensure any settings I add (like multiline/numberOfLines={4}) get passed down and used by the actual TextInput?

Comment: You are already passing {...props} so it should work

Comment: Hmm, yeah I added an alert to that changetexthandler and it worked. I think there's some default iOS behaviour where it doesn't show the full size input, because it let me use the return key to add line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

To really be sure everything in need is passed down, you should do props validation, as [explained here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html).

> React has some built-in typechecking abilities. To run typechecking on
> the props for a component, you can assign the special propTypes

You would use it like:

```
TextInputField.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string,
   [.....]
};
```

Comment: Thanks, think I worked it out. I was expecting to see the full area available in iOS but it doesn't look like that's how it functions- iOS let me use the return key to add line breaks with multiline set, and wouldn't let me if it wasn't.